# HTML/CSS won't keep page consistent in different sizes

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a website which looks good on my monitor but if I were to zoom in or zoom out it doesn't look good anymore.

I tried various ways of trying to fix this but can't seem to figure out a good solution.
Can anyone help me? I can give all the files for you to try it locally or you can connect through teamviewer to my pc if you'd like.

If you wonder what I'm on about, here's how it looks like right now live:
http://marcus-engineer.tk/

Comment: I don't see the problem. Firefox 22 zooms in 5 or six times without changing layout. Is this browser-specific?

Comment: You should be using a **responsive** method with `@media` CSS queries. Zoom shouldn't be a factor, nor should you even bother worrying about it. You should be worrying about whether your site will be viewable by all or most computer screens and mobile devices. **Fixed width** is "passé", and should you be fixed on using it, would work for `@media` queries only.

Comment: It looks good on Firefox ?
For me when I zoom in, the "Lorem ipsum" on the right side pops down below the contents area (the middle square).

What do you mean by a responsive method?

Comment: @MarcusEkström http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: @MarcusEkström Responsive web design can prove to be a bit difficult at first, but believe me it is well worth the effort.

Comment: So basically you recon I should be making a redirection for smartphones/tablets etc, is that so?
I thought of doing it before but never really did it

Comment: @MarcusEkström Here is another link worth reading, and you should look up **Bootstrap** also. http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/

Comment: @MarcusEkström No, that's not what responsive design is, it is not "redirection", it is designing to accomodate different screen sizes etc.. P.s.: Please add the `@` symbol in front of my name, to address me.

Comment: @MarcusEkström Here is another article on the subject, which I must add is a great one at that, one of the first ones I read some time back when I started out. Includes examples: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Comment: @MarcusEkström Another thing, I noticed you're using **"frames"**. That is slowly being phased out and no longer supported by many devices.

Comment: @Fred yea sorry, I'm still quite new to Stackovwerflow .. as I wrote in a comment further down I'm renovating the website. So the frames is from the previous design and has been removed now from my local machine, just not updated to the webhotel, will update in a sec, transfering files now. Also.. I'll read those links carefully, thanks tons for taking your time finding them for me. I appreciate it. It's a good study.

Comment: @MarcusEkström My pleasure Marcus and welcome to SO :) In regards to the answer you accepted below, I don't recommend you using a `fixed width` unless you will be using a `redirection` method; you will be far better off in using a responsive method. The fixed width is fine if using `@media` queries, shown from an example that `Chunk` provided below, as well as the links I gave you earlier.

Comment: @Fred Yea I've looked into the responsive method, it seems to be a bit too much work for me to do right now but I might implent it some other time. We'll see.
For now I'll suffice with the fixed width method. Better than nothing.

Comment: @MarcusEkström I understand. It took me a long time to "jump head first" into it myself, but was well worth it. If you're not going to go towards that route for now, then I suggest you use `percentage` instead of `pixels`. That will work in your favor, I'm sure. All the best, cheers.

Comment: @MarcusEkström **Food for thought**: You'll end up working 5-10 times as hard later on to probably transform your Website into a responsive type. **Name your elements** so that it will ease the pressure down the road. Spending a mere 8-10 hours to study responsive design, will save you much more time down the road. Any way, it's your choice. When I think back, I should've taken up responsive design when I had the chance, many years ago. I **strongly** suggest you do the same. We are in an era of **iPhones, mobiles, iPad, etc.** and old methods are **out**.

Comment: @Fred hey again .. marucs-engineer.tk ..  I still can't get the menubars buttons to get centered.. I want them evenly centered but don't know how to go it. Text-align: center; and float middle doesn't work.. honestly, I don't even know the difference between float and text-align

Comment: @MarcusEkström Hi Marcus. Try this `margin: 0 auto;` for your nav menu. Usually works. And maybe add `text-align:center;`. See what that does.

Comment: @MarcusEkström Took a quick look at your source. This `<div id="centered">`. Even when you make an ID and try to center it, doesn't always work. Try adding a `align="center"` such as `<div id="centered" align="center">`.

Comment: @MarcusEkström Also noticed in your CSS `margin: 60px auto;` under `#menu`. Change that to `margin: 0 auto;` and for `#top_menu` also.

Comment: @Fred I changed those locally but didn't solve the problem. I would upload it but the web hotel is having technical issues right now so I can't. Any other idea?

Comment: @MarcusEkström Hi Marcus. I spent a bit more time in trying to figure what the problem but your CSS is far too erratic for me to understand how to fix. Sorry. I suggest you start fresh.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best solution for you would be to put all of your content in a div and give it some fixed width (and center it). That way the content will appear the same on all resolutions.

Many site do it like this and they have a nice background image behind that div.

Comment: But if I give it a fixed width .. wouldn't it look strange for people with smaller resolution than the width?

Comment: That is why you have to make it so it looks good on small screens and have a background to show on large screens.

Comment: Give an example to the OP.

Comment: I fixed it now locally with a min-width..
I think it's working fine.
Got another issue now though. .
The reason I got these problems is because I'm "renovating" the website .. so yea that's why. Now I'm just wanting to extend the "shade" behind the nav bar a bit further down but not sure how so testing my way. ;D


Edit:
fixed that as well by adding padding to my #Top_Menu div.
it seems a bit bugged though? 1 px is like 1 cm ^^ oh well, works anyway so it's nice

Comment: What if the fixed width is `800px`? iPhone/mobile users etc. will have to compensate and I for one, will visit another website if that's the case. There are methods at our disposal today in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to link different stylesheets to the page for different window sizes, or you can use them inside a stylesheet to specify styles for an element with different window sizes.

Linking stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 720px)" href="example.css" />
```

Or inside a stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width: 650px){
  #myElement{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is worthy as a comment. You should be providing an example, since you do not have enough rep points to comment.

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer to provide examples

Comment: Good stuff. I mentioned you in a comment above.

Comment: (`+1`) For the example, cheers ;-)

Comment: @Chunk on the linking method.. about "media='(max-width; 720px)'" .. is that max width on the display?

Comment: @MarcusEkström `max-width: 720px` means to load a stylesheet for displays `up to` that amount of pixel display. Anything over that, will use the default settings your page syntax has for each element, or any other stylesheet loaded.

Comment: @MarcusEkström Sorry it took so long to respond, but Fred is right, and also `min-width` works conversely and you can do the same with the height if you so pleased. Using min-width and max-width together can help when using multiple style sheets.